# Automate: importing xls to table (without microsoft excel)

Tags: sql-server, bulk-insert

I am importing 5 different reports from payment sites (paypal, worldpay, etc)

It works like a charm using csv!

```
BULK

INSERT Report_Table

FROM '\\Files_Server\departments\finance\Paypal.csv'

WITH

(

FIRSTROW=2,

FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',

ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'

)
```

But there is this one site that gives us an .xls file (Excel 97-2003 Worksheet).

I can’t use SSIS because in the server I don’t have excel installed and I don’t have permission to install it… My question is, if I convert it myself from xls to csv, will I be able to **BULK INSERT** it easlly, or it will contain garbage remaning from the xls to csv conversion?!

Options I see:

```
1-      ssis (I can’t install excel on the server).

2-      convert xls to csv and then bulk insert? (can I?)
```

What other options do you see/recommend?

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't need to install excel on your server.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to install Excel on the server to import with SSIS, you only need the "Access Database Engine", which is simply the data access layer:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

We definitely don't have Excel installed on our database server, and Excel imports work just fine with this.

Comment: Thanks for providing the exact link. Small doubt: just to be extra-sure if I am given an .xls, there is no point in converting to csv and using Bulk Insert… right? I should always go with SSIS.

Comment: @Chicago1988 That would be my recommendation. The Excel-to-CSV conversion would either have to be done manually, or automated with SSIS, in which case you need the Access Database Engine anyway. :) Also, I believe you can sidestep SSIS and query Excel files directly with `OPENQUERY` if you've got this installed, depending on what the situation calls for.

Comment: in case linked server or OPENROWSET is used this might come in handy for understanding connection strings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102149/what-is-imex-in-the-oledb-connection-string